# Joptionpane o jdialog?

Tags: java

estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal en java y quisiera un consejo, quiero hacer unas notificaciones personalizadas para mostrar mensajes de error, alerta etc. La pregunta es, que opción es más recomendable, personalizar un joptionpane o un jdialog? Que consecuencias trae usar uno o el otro?

Muchas gracias

Comment: La pregunta es basada en opiniones, lo cual generaría su cierre, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: yo usaría un JOptionPane mientras no requiera en específico un JDialog. Sí el JOptionPane puede mostrar los mensajes lo uso. Si de plano necesito algo adicional entonces pensaría en el JDialog.